# Function summary in Google format not showing up in the quick documentation window in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, docstring

PyCharm 2018.3 has an option to change your docstring format under File > Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools > Docstring Format

After selecting 'Google', I write code like:

```py
def my_func(a, b):
    """
    Do something with a and b

    Args:
        a: first arg
        b: second arg

    Returns:
        something

    """
    pass
```

I want the summary i.e. "Do something with a and b" in addition to the arguments to show up in the quick documentation window but all I get is this

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Using Pycharm Professional 2018.3.5, and copying your exact example, I was unable to reproduce the error. (I placed this response as an answer because it could serve to move your research closer to the answer.)

Here was my outcome from Quick Documentation:

```
def my_func(a: Any,
            b: Any) -> None
Do something with a and b
Params:
a – first arg
b – second arg
Returns:
something
```